# I have no WiFi option avaliable

Tags: wifi, drivers

I just switch to Elementary OS a couple of days ago. I'm in troubles, because i can't connect my laptop (Notebook HP - 15-da0004la) the option to connect wirless doesn't even appear, i can only connect to internet via Ethernet. I have tried a lot of thing i've read on internet, i'm just gonna paste the history here. Also is important to say the Network Controller is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter,

History:

```
    1  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
    2  sudo modprobe rtl8723de
    3  sudo sed -i '/blacklist bcma/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
    4  sudo sed -i '/blacklist brcmsmac/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
    5  sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
    6  lspci
    7  lspci -k | more
    8  pci | less
    9  :~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install git dkms
   10  :sudo apt update && sudo apt install git dkms
   11  sudo apt install git dkms
   12  :~$ cd Downloads
   13  :~$ git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
   14  unofficial
   15  :~$ cd rtlwifi_new
   16  Now, either you can run:
   17  :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ make 
   18  :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo make install
   19  OR use dkms to build and manage the modules:
   20  :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms add ../rtlwifi_new
   21  :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6 
   22  :~/Downloads/rtlwifi_new$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
   23  :~/Downloads/rtl-new/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723de ant_sel=2
   24  lshw -C network
   25  lshw -C network
   26  lspci | grep -i wireless
   27  sudo update-pciids
   28  lspci -v
   29  lspci
   30  uname -r
   31  su”/”sudo
   32  $ sudo reboot
   33  sudo reboot
   34  sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
   35  modinfo rtl8723de
   36  sudo apt install inxi
   37  sudo reboot
   38  inxi -Fxz
   39  modinfo rtl8723de
   40  sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
   41  modinfo rtl8723de
   42  git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up
   43  dkms add ./rtl8723de
   44  dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
   45  depmod -a
   46  sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
   47  dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
   48  depmod -a
   49  sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
   50  depmode -a
   51  sudo password root
   52  sudo passwd root
   53  su -
   54  history
   55  sudo apt install --install-recommends linix-generic-hwe-18.04
   56  sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
   57  git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
   58  sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
   59  sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
   60  boot
   61  reboot
   62  history
   63  sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
   64  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
   65  reboot
   66  history
   67  sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
   68  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
   69  reboot
   70  history
```

I really need help

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can help you

Check if you have `indicator-applet` & `indicator-application` installed or not.

If you already have them installed, try reinstalling `libappindicator` and then logout and log back in.

Use the following command to reinstall `libappindicator`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libappindicator3-1 libappindicator1
```

If the above solutions doesn't work. Try reinstalling the network manager

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```